# CSS background image struggles

Tags: css, html, background

I'm trying to add an image in background but I want to use internal CSS and I can't find what's wrong. The font is ok but the background doesn't appear.

**Here is my code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body:{font-family: Arial}
        body:{background:url("C:\Users\Sonik379\Downloads\backPortfolio.jpg");}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Hello world</p>
</body> 



</html>
```

Comment: remove `:` after body tag.

Comment: A reference for you. How to write a css selector.  [Click here](http://www.w3schools.com/css)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body{
            font-family: Arial;
            background:url("C:\Users\Sonik379\Downloads\backPortfolio.jpg");
                 }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>Hello world</p>
    </body> 
    </html>
```

Comment: Still doesn't work I decided to do the background with the style attribute(no  CSS. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the path, you can try this:

```
<style>body{background:url(file:///C:/Users/Sonik379/Downloads/backPortfolio.jpg);}</style>
```

Comment: @KheemaPandey what did I miss? This is what I always do, for example:`{background: url(../images/body-bg.jpg) center 0 repeat #1c1c1c;}` this is working for me. Please let me know what I missed.